# db4o on android

Tags: android, database, android-emulator, db4o

I'm a new to developing for android.I use the db4o database in my first project.
But I get an error with the following code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            //only want to get the configuration
       EmbeddedConfiguration configuration = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();//This one will popup 
    }
```

> 

```
the error log :
06-14 20:15:30.249: W/dalvikvm(445): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
06-14 20:15:30.249: E/AndroidRuntime(445): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-14 20:15:30.289: E/AndroidRuntime(445): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded
06-14 20:15:30.289: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at com.hlh.AtestActivity.onCreate(AtestActivity.java:34)
06-14 20:15:30.289: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-14 20:15:30.289: E/AndroidRuntime(445):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
```

I feel very confused why does it work when I use it in a java project but it does not work in an android project
Are there some restrictions in Android for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds lilke you don't have the library .jar in the correct place.

For android it needs to be in a subfolder of your project called `libs` which should be on the same level as `assets` and `res` and the like (this was a recent change if you don't remember having to do this previously).

Simply create that folder and drop your jar in there and Eclipse will take care of the rest.